# Can I somehow run the Windows version of Spotify on Linux?

Tags: spotify

I was wondering if I could somehow run the windows version of Spotify through wine or something, cause the native Spotify on Linux sucks with features missing, like making text smaller and zooming out, which I can't live without. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: You might want to check on [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8514) for compatibility info before just trying it. Also I imagine it's against the T&Cs. Another way to run it is in a VM (eg Virtualbox).

Comment: Using the web version may be worth looking into too.